# Is there a way for Excel VBA to automatically detect groups of data (groups separated by blank rows) and write averages of the data to another column?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I am trying to calculate daily averages of the availability and performance of machines. In the raw data, each machine has a different number of data points that are needed to make an average from.

Is there a way to get VBA to auto-detect the group of rows, and from then, take the average of the data in those rows?

At the moment, I have it being completed in an inefficient and buggy way held together by duct tape. The ActiveCell moves down until it finds a non-blank cell. It stores the value of the cell into an array and adds more data until it reaches a blank row. Then, it writes the value to the average column, clears the array, and moves down until it reaches a non-blank cell.

I am aware that ActiveCell.select is a terrible way to code, but I don't know of any more elegant ways to accomplish this task.

A sample of how the data will look

[image]

Comment: Will the Machine group ever be duplicated.  ie will `L12` ever have a second grouping?

Comment: No, the machine group won't be duplicated as a grouping

Comment: Then just use AVERAGEIFS()

Comment: In that case, the criteria would be only rows that have, for example, L12 in column A?

Comment: Put: `=IF($A3="",AVERAGEIFS(B:B,$A:$A,$A2),"")` in E2 copy over one column and then both down to the end of the data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know there will not be duplicated machines, `AverageIfs()` is a great option, just make sure to add an `And()` to check current row and next row as seem below.

If there may be duplicated machines, you can use `XMatch()` to find the first empty row, and use either `indirect()` to build your `AverageIfs()` formula (like i did... but only useful if your data will always be in the same place) or use `XMatch()` along with `Offset()` and `Sum()` if you need the data to move more easily. One drawback is requiring a blank row at the top of the data, but this could be worked around with an additional if statement.

Please note: Yellow cells indicate where the formula was pulled from.

[image: Formula Examples]